# matplotlib: how to constrain mouse event handling to top-most artist?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a method  in matplotlib to create multiple interactive artists (i.e. rectangles, circles, etc) in a single axis that can be resized/rotated/moved using the mouse. I successfully tried [this example](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#draggable-rectangle-exercise) to create a "draggable" rectangle in matplotlib. However, when two such draggable rectangles overlap, both will move and not just the top-most one as I would like. How can I make sure that only the top-most artist under the mouse pointer will respond to mouse events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to set the zorder of each rectangle. And then use this zorder in the on_push event to pick the right object to move. I modified the code of the example given to do this. I commented out the on_press event handler for DraggableRectangle and added another class for handling the on_press event.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class DraggableRectangle:
    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect
        self.press = None

    def connect(self):
        'connect to all the events we need'
        #self.cidpress = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
        #    'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        'on button press we will see if the mouse is over us and store some data'
        if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes: return

        contains, attrd = self.rect.contains(event)
        if not contains: return
        print 'event contains', self.rect.xy

        x0, y0 = self.rect.xy
        self.press = x0, y0, event.xdata, event.ydata

    def on_motion(self, event):
        'on motion we will move the rect if the mouse is over us'
        if self.press is None: return
        if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes: return
        x0, y0, xpress, ypress = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress
        #print 'x0=%f, xpress=%f, event.xdata=%f, dx=%f, x0+dx=%f'%(x0, xpress, event.xdata, dx, x0+dx)
        self.rect.set_x(x0+dx)
        self.rect.set_y(y0+dy)

        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()


    def on_release(self, event):
        'on release we reset the press data'
        self.press = None
        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()

    def disconnect(self):
        'disconnect all the stored connection ids'
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)

class RectangleHandler():

    def __init__(self, drs):
        self.drs = drs
        self.ax = drs[0].rect.axes

        self.cidpress = self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_press_event', self.on_press)

    def on_press(self, event):
        if event.inaxes != self.ax: return
        for dr in self.drs:
            rect = dr.rect
            contains, attrd = rect.contains(event)
            if contains:
                zorder = rect.zorder
                try:
                    if zorder > maxZorder: 
                        maxZorder = zorder
                        rectToDrag = dr
                except NameError:
                    maxZorder = zorder
                    rectToDrag = dr
        try:
            if rectToDrag:
                rectToDrag.on_press(event)
        except UnboundLocalError:
            pass


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects = ax.bar(range(10), 20*np.random.rand(10))
drs = []
for i, rect in enumerate(rects):
    rect.zorder = i
    dr = DraggableRectangle(rect)
    dr.connect()
    drs.append(dr)

rh = RectangleHandler(drs)
plt.show()
```